# Coupling constant problem

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In the scalar $φ^4$ theory  we write Lagrangian as $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_t\phi)^2 -\frac{1}{2}\delta^{ij}\partial_i\phi\partial_j\phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2-\frac{g}{4!}\phi^4. $$
I want to know details about the coupling strength g. How will I start? 
I studied some technique from Feynman diagram, that it represents the strength of a scattering. But I need to find out the value of this constant and need  guideline how will I study so I can understand clearly.

Is there any relationship which  gives us the enough  evidence for putting the  coupling constant into Lagrangian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about the running of the coupling, then you have to solve the one loop beta function for this theory:
$\beta(g^2)=\mu   \frac{\partial g^2}{\partial \mu}=\frac{9}{2\pi^2}g^4+O(g^6)$
The solution of this differential equation reads $\frac{1}{g^2_\mu}=\frac{1}{g^2_\Lambda}+\frac{9}{2\pi^2}\ln\frac{\Lambda}{\mu}$ where $\mu$ is the energy scale at which you want to know the value of the coupling and $\Lambda$ is an ultra-violett cut off. $g^2_\Lambda$ is the value of the coupling at the cut-off and remains an open parameter. You see you still have to know the value of the coupling at one energy scale, but then you can calculate the running of the coupling in first order.